# Looping over a JSON file full of clothes products and for every product check if the title contains a certain word

Tags: javascript, json

```
$(function() {
$.getJSON('test.json', function(data) {
  for (var i = 0; i < data.products.length; i++) {
    var obj = data.products[i];
    if (obj.title.toLowerCase().includes("t-shirt")) {
      var Imgs = '<div class="Tops"><img src="' + obj.imUrl + '"></div>'
      $(Imgs).appendTo($(".TopsImages"));
    }
      var bought_together_id = obj.related["bought_together"];
      if (obj.asin in bought_together_id) {
        if (obj.title.toLowerCase().includes("sandal")) {
          var Imgs = '<div class="Shoes"><img src="' + obj.imUrl + '"></div>'
          $(Imgs).appendTo($(".ShoesImages"));
        }
      }
    }
  })
})
```

- asin = ID
- imUrl is the image field where the image url is saved

So to explain my javascript code a bit, I am using a for loop to loop over every product and its data from a JSON file. I want to read each product one at a time, I have put a snippet of what my json file looks like underneath.

So the first part I have managed to do, I want to read the title field of the product then check if the title contains "t-shirt", "hat", "pants/jean" or "shoes" then display the 'imUrl' value of the product in the right div class, for example. TopsImages, PantsImages, ShoesImages or HatsImages.

Now is the tough part, so I'm trying to then read the 'bought_together' field values of the same product one at a time which are three different IDs of three different products. So then I want to find the data for the IDs check if the title field of that product contains "t-shirt", "hat", "pants/jean" or "shoes" then display the 'imUrl' value of the product in the right div class, for example. TopsImages, PantsImages, ShoesImages or HatsImages.

Then repeat that for the other 2 bought_together product IDs until a full outfit is made. Then I'm going have arrows left and right and when the right arrow is clicked it will then move onto the second product and do this process for that product then so on.

To summarize what I need help with, after reading the 'bought_together' list of IDs from the product data I am struggling to then look for the product that the ID belongs to in the JSON file one at a time.

This part of my code is where I'm trying to accomplish it but `obj.asin in bought_together_id` is only checking the first products ID and not the whole JSON file.

```
var bought_together_id = obj.related["bought_together"];
if (obj.asin in bought_together_id) {
    if (obj.title.toLowerCase().includes("sandal")) {
        var Imgs = '<div class="Shoes"><img src="' + obj.imUrl + '"></div>'
        $(Imgs).appendTo($(".ShoesImages"));
    }
}
```

Here is a snippet of my JSON file so you can have an idea of what I'm working with. My JSON file consists of about 10 of these snippets making it 10 products.

```
{
  "products": [{
    "asin": "B0001MQ60A",
    "title": "KEEN Men's Newport H2 Sandal",
    "imUrl": "http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/41pRaO7fFSL._SX395_.jpg",
    "related": {
      "also_bought": ["B000MN8OR6"],
      "also_viewed": ["B0000DYKET", "B0035FE60M", "B008KI85R4", "B000MQWVA4",
        "B003Z4KHXS", "B00GUBOCGQ",
        "B003O2SLXY", "B0017KSRMA", "B003O2SBKM", "B00DSN637U", "B000HDJ8IK", "B00E0J3HVG", "B003Z4KGZW",
        "B005HO2CYG", "B003H4QFVY", "B0017LB2VC", "B002R8JPTK", "B008KI84SE", "B005DJDL9A", "B003TU14OE",
        "B00E0J3HTI", "B000EDTVYY", "B003Z4JOJG", "B00DSN638E", "B00E0J3HVQ", "B008KI88JY", "B00EZIRE20",
        "B0095RGEH2", "B00CEX6MSU", "B000B84URK", "B003O2SPMG", "B002KKCWP4", "B003O2SLXE", "B00JQHFV0M",
        "B008JE8V14", "B0055ATVDW", "B003Z4KLMA", "B008ZAY40Y", "B003H4QFV4", "B00DSN64BU", "B002KKCZLA",
        "B0055ATVV4", "B00HFY47JY", "B00DPHJUTW", "B008FWRJ6I", "B003Z4JUFO", "B00JFB4RL8", "B00HR1LTNM",
        "B005HMTPBG", "B00KCT84I4", "B00HXDITEG"
      ],
      "bought_together": ["B003O2SLXY", "B003H4QFVY", "B000EDTVYY"]
    },
    "salesRank": {
      "Shoes": 18
    },
    "categories": [
      ["Clothing, Shoes & Jewelry", "Shoes & Accessories: International Shipping Available"],
      ["Clothing, Shoes & Jewelry", "K", "Keen"],
      ["Clothing, Shoes & Jewelry", "Comfort Shoes"],
      ["Clothing, Shoes & Jewelry", "Men", "Shoes", "Sandals"],
      ["Clothing, Shoes & Jewelry", "Men", "Shoes", "Athletic", "Sport Sandals"]
    ]
  }]
}
```

Here is my HTML too that is involved with the rest of this code, I just four empty divs for the four different types of clothing.

```
<article class="column large-2">
    <div class="HatsImages">

    </div>
    <div class="TopsImages">

    </div>
    <div class="PantsImages">

    </div>
    <div class="ShoesImages">

    </div>
</article>
```

Comment: could you please add HTML too ?

Comment: Where do you search this **bought_together** ?

Comment: @AlpeshJikadra `var bought_together_id = obj.related["bought_together"];` Here

Answer (score 0):

I think It should be `if (bought_together_id.indexOf(obj.asin) > -1) {`

```
console.log(obj.asin in bought_together_id); -> false
console.log(bought_together_id.indexOf(obj.asin) > -1); -> true
```

NOTE: I couldn't find any document for "String `in` Array"; like obj.asin in bought_together_id

Answer (score 0):

There is an issue in your if condition at line #**11(if (obj.asin in bought_together_id) {**)

Try following code,

```
$(function() {
$.getJSON('test.json', function(data) {
    var data = JSON.parse(d);
  for (var i = 0; i < data.products.length; i++) {
    var obj = data.products[i];
    if (obj.title.toLowerCase().includes("t-shirt")) {
      var Imgs = '<div class="Tops"><img src="' + obj.imUrl + '"></div>'
      $(Imgs).appendTo($(".TopsImages"));
    }
      var bought_together_id = obj.related["bought_together"];
      if (bought_together_id.indexOf(obj.asin)  >=0) {
        if (obj.title.toLowerCase().includes("sandal")) {
          var Imgs = '<div class="Shoes"><img src="' + obj.imUrl + '"></div>'
          $(Imgs).appendTo($(".ShoesImages"));
        }
      }
    }
});
```